# Swift: UIView.transitionWithView completion block issues

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I'm trying to have my UIImageView (`self.posterImageview`) cycle through a set of UIImages with an animation using the follow code:

```
 func animatePoster (imageArray: [UIImage], count: Int = 0)
{
            UIView.transitionWithView
            (
                self.posterImageview,
                duration: 2,
                options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromBottom,
                animations:
                {
                    self.posterImageview.image = imageArray[count]
                },
                completion: 
                {
                    finished in
                    if (count == imageArray.count - 1)  // Last image
                    {
                        self.animatePoster(imageArray)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    self.animatePoster(imageArray, count: count + 1)
                    }
                }
            )

}
```

However it appears the completion block is not working how I imagined it should. Right now it flickers repeatedly through all the images without allowing the full animation to play before moving on to the next one. Increasing the duration of the animation does not help, and when I set a restriction on the recursion (for example, ending when I reach the final image), then all images are cycled through quickly except for the final one, which animates in correctly.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: So the completion handler is simply called when the animation "succeeds", not when the actual animation terminates...if you call `self.animatePoster()` on a delay equal to your animation duration, what happens?

Comment: Calling it on a delay does in fact fix the problem. I wasn't aware this was how the completion handler operated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The documentation suggests otherwise.  I'd check the `finished` flag.

Answer (score 0):

I have made few changes for show `animation` differently. Please check may be it will helpful to you.

For now i have added dummy `code`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.arrimages = NSArray (arrayLiteral: UIImage(named: "1.png")!,UIImage(named: "2.png")!,UIImage(named: "3.png")!,UIImage(named: "4.png")!)

        print("Images array = \(self.arrimages)")

        self.posterImageview.image = UIImage(named: "1.png")!
        self.animatePoster(self.arrimages as! [UIImage], count: 1)

    }


    func animatePoster (imageArray: [UIImage], count: Int = 0){

        print("count value = \(count)")

        UIView.transitionWithView(self.posterImageview, duration: 5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromBottom, animations: {

            }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> () in

                let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))

                dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.posterImageview.image = imageArray[count]
                }


                if (count == (imageArray.count - 1))  // Last image
                {
                    let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(4 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))

                    dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.animatePoster(imageArray)
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(4 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))

                    dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.animatePoster(imageArray, count: count + 1)
                    }
                }
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have some trouble with bounds of your view.

For understanding, place this code in playground. *To place images just drag'n'drop inside.*

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 240))
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = imageView // show layer in Playground timeline, don't forget to open right panel

func animate(images: [UIImage], index: Int = 0) {
    UIView.transitionWithView(imageView, duration: 2, options: .TransitionFlipFromBottom, animations: {
        imageView.image = images[index]
    }, completion: { value in
        let idx = index == images.count-1 ? 0 : index+1
        animate(images, index: idx)
    })
}

animate([UIImage(imageLiteral: "1.png"), UIImage(imageLiteral: "2.png"), UIImage(imageLiteral: "3.png")])
```

Answer (score 0):

The comments on your main post lead to interesting places. I'd suggest that you check the finished parameter, as [chrisco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2171044/chrisco) suggests. If finished is `NO`, the most likely cause of the completion handler being called before it is finished is because the animation is cancelled -- often because another one has been kicked off. Is it possible that you're triggering a second animation before the first one is finished somehow? I don't see that in your current code, but ... we can't see other elements of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Created extension from @dimpiax's answer

Here is the code:

```
extension UIImageView {

    func animate(images: [UIImage], index: Int = 0, completionHandler: (() -> Void)?) {

        UIView.transition(with: self, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            self.image = images[index]

        }, completion: { value in
            let idx = index == images.count-1 ? 0 : index+1

            if idx == 0 {
                completionHandler!()

            } else {
                self.animate(images: images, index: idx, completionHandler: completionHandler)
            }

        })
    }

}
```